# Android Service with a loop?

Tags: android, service, intentservice, sticky, foreground-service

I need to create a background service that starts and stops with two buttons. My service will cycle every 5 minutes and it will take data from an online database. I read somewhere that IntentService class is not used for loops. I would override onStartCommand so it will return START_STICKY. If i do that in this class my service doesn't start. How can I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void start(View view){
        startService(new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class));
    }

    public void stop(View view){
        stopService(new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class));
    }
}




public class ForegroundService extends IntentService{

    private boolean stato;


    public ForegroundService(){
        super("ForegroundService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent i){
        stato = true;
        int n=0;
        while(stato)
        {
            Log.i("PROVA SERVICE", "Evento n."+n++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            { }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stato = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Only have a service running when it is *actively delivering value to the user*](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Sitting and watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user.

Also, please understand that what you want ("cycle every 5 minutes and it will take data from an online database") may not be what the user wants and certainly is not what Google wants. Too many developers are doing stuff like this, and battery life is suffering as a result.

Generally speaking, your best solution (given your stated objective) is `JobScheduler`, perhaps falling back to `AlarmManager` if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21. Both of those allow you to schedule periodic work. Your process does not need to be running in between those bits of work. You teach `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager` how frequently to trigger the work, and you do the work in a `JobService` or `IntentService`.

Just bear in mind that on Android 6.0+, unless the user tells Android via the Settings app to leave your app alone, your app will eventually enter [Doze mode or app standby mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), and you will not be able to get control every five minutes.

Comment: You opened my mind! I'm studying AlarmManager in next hours. About Android 6.0+ I can use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). I'll post my new code here as answer when it works, thank you!